# How to convert existing POCO classes in C# to google Protobuf standard POCO

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have POCO classes , I use NewtonSoft json for seralization. Now i want to migrate it to Google protocol buff. Is there any way i can migrate all my classes (not manually) so that i can use google protocol buff for serialization and deseralization.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want it to work? The *absolute simplest* way to do this would be to use protobuf-net and add `[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]`. What this does is tell protobuf-net to *make up the field numbers*, which it does by taking all the public members, sorting them alphabetically, and just counting upwards. Then you can use your type with `ProtoBuf.Serializer` and it should behave in the way you expect.

This is *simple*, but it isn't very robust. If you add, remove or rename members it can all get out of sync. The problem here is that the protocol buffers format doesn't include *names* - just *field numbers*, and it is much harder to guarantee *numbers* over time. If your type is likely to change, you probably want to define field numbers explicitly. For example:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public List<string> Names {get;} = new List<string>();
}
```

One other thing to watch out for would be non-zero default values. By default protobuf-net assumes certain things about implicit default values. If you are routinely using non-zero default values *without* doing it very carefully, protobuf-net may misunderstand you. You can turn that off globally if you desire:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.UseImplicitZeroDefaults = false;
```